# find an Invertible function on a Cartesian product

Tags: functions

Hi I am trying to find a strategy/ example to find an invertible function on a Cartesian product. Let's say I want to find an invertible function from $[1,n]\times [1,n]\rightarrow [0,n^2-1]$

Comment: Are these sets of integers of intervals of real numbers?

Comment: these are sets of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your notation is
$$
[a, b] = \left\{ k \in \Bbb{Z} \mid a \le k \le b \right\}.
$$

---

The map $\alpha : [1, n] \times [1, n] \to [0, n^2 - 1]$ given by
$$
\alpha(r, c) = (r - 1)n + c - 1,
$$
is a bijection.  You can imagine $r$ and $c$ stand for *row* and *column*, respectively, as in the standard indexing of a matrix.

Now, if $\beta: [0, n^2 - 1] \to [0, n^2 - 1]$ is any permutation, then
$$
\beta \circ \alpha
$$
is a bijection.  In other words, there are $(n^2 - 1)!$ possible invertible functions.

---

**Added to respond to comment**

The inverse is:
$$
\alpha^{-1}(k) = \left( 1 + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{n} \right\rfloor, 1 + (k \!\!\mod n) \right),
$$
where $k \!\!\mod n = k - n \left\lfloor \frac{k}{n} \right\rfloor$ gives the remainder in $\{ 0, 1, \ldots, n - 1 \}$ when $k$ is divided by $n$.

Comment: thanks for the answer but how would you determine the inverse function g $[0,n^2-1]\rightarrow [1,n]\times [1,n] $

Comment: Do you want an explicit function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the notation $\left[a,b\right]\equiv\left\{ a,\ldots,b\right\} $,
then the domain and codomain have the same (finite) cardinality. Any
isomorphism will work. Take for example
$$
f\left(i,j\right)=\left(i-1\right)+\left(j-1\right)n.
$$

I think some people refer to the ordering induced by $f$ as the "natural
ordering" (I use quotation marks here because the term "natural order"
is usually used in a different context). In general, if you have 
$$
\left[1,n_{1}\right]\times\left[1,n_{2}\right]\times\ldots\times\left[1,n_{N}\right]
$$
(i.e. an $N$-tuple instead of a 2-tuple) then
$$
f\left(i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{N}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(i_{j}-1\right)\prod_{k=1}^{i-1}n_{k}
$$
induces the "natural ordering."

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I like to think about these type of problems (not necessarily the best approach)

Consider the Cartesian Plane ($XY$-plane) and draw and $n+1$ by $n+1$ square. Then highlight all the points of the form $(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers. i.e, all the points with integer coordinates inside the square.

Now, draw a circle whose center is the origin and the radius is $\sqrt{2(n+1)^2}$. Note that this is exactly the unique circle that passes through the only corner of your square that is not on the axis, and $\sqrt{2(n+1)^2}$ is the radius of such a circle, which is the same as the diagonal of the square.

Now, try to connect each of those points inside the square, whose both coordinates are integers, to the circle that surrounds the square in the first quarter of the plane such that the line does not go through any other point of  the aforementioned form. Doing so, you will correspond a unique point on the circle to every single point inside the square with integer coefficients.

You should have obtained exactly $n^2$ points on the circle (of course in the first quarter). Now, you can label them in every order you like, from  $0$  to $n^2-1$ which could be done in $n^2$ factorial ways.